# What is the recommended approach for organizing a large number of components in a React app?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app that is starting to get larger, and I'm finding it increasingly difficult to manage all the components. The components folder is getting very large, and it's becoming hard to find and maintain the components.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to structure the app so that it's easier to manage and navigate. Should I just keep them all in the components folder, or should I create subfolders within the components folder?

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think go for modular approach. Second make generic components and based on your props you pass in them handle the component view or functionality.

Comment: you can have a look at "atomic design" (https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) to see if this suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say that there is no one best way of structuring. It depends on the app and your own preferences.
From my experience I could recommend couple of ways that might be helpful:

1. Create a folder for each main page you are creating (eg: login, payment, shop etc) and inside each one create a subfolder: **'component'** that would contain all sub components related **specifically** to this page.
   Inside the main folder you will have your index.js file that would render all of the components inside your component folder. (this way you can break your code into much smaller parts in a nicer and cleaner way)
2. In case you create reusable components that will be used cross-app you can create a new folder, eg: **'commonComponent'**, and put all of them inside it.
3. Of course you should create a **utils** folder that would contain functions that are reusable, such as: date formatting, prices convertor etc, and I would also recommend to move all constant data you have to a new file as well (you can also create a new sub folder (eg: **constantData**) and organize your constant data in files with the same name as your page name - all in order to keep your structure understandable and easy to navigate)

so you will get something like:

### commonComponent:

```
Header
Footer
MyButton
etc....
index.js (with all the exports for the common components)
```

### pages:

```
logInPage:
    components:
         logInForm
    index.js
createNewUser:
    components:
        newUserDetailsForm
        submitUserModal
    index.js
```

### utils:

```
 commonFunctions.js
 constantData:
     createNewUserConst.js
```

this is what I came up with right now.